# Modify Windows Command Prompt History from a Program?

Tags: windows, console, cmd

Is there an API to add to the a windows command prompt history? I writing a console program and it would be handy to pop some commands into the history buffer under certain (limited) conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for that.  The history is just a buffer of the commands that the user has typed in during that command session.  Once the command window has been closed, the history is gone.

Comment: It's OK that the history gets killed when the command window is closed. The question remains. Is there a way to put commands in this buffer from a console program?

Comment: Like I said earlier, there is no API for accessing the console's history.